# How to combine two counts on one table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

The table is like:

| country | fruit | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | Apple | Big |
| Japan | Apple | Small |
| Japan | Orange | Big |
| Singapore | Banana | Small |

The expect output is like:

| country | type | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | 2 | 3 |
| Singapore | 1 | 1 |

I managed to run the counts separately.
Fruit type:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) AS type 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY country
```

Fruit total:

```
SELECT COUNT(fruit) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: You're almost there. Give it one more try, have COUNT(DISTINCT fruit)  and COUNT(fruit)  in the same query.

Comment: BTW, _columns_, not fields.

Comment: The actual table definition matters. Which columns are defined `NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your queries into one :

```
SELECT country, COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) AS type, COUNT(fruit) as total
FROM Table
GROUP BY country;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like has been commented, you can simply put both aggregates in the same `SELECT` list. `count(*)` is faster. One difference: it counts all rows, while `count(fruit)` only counts non-null values. If fruit is `NOT NULL`, both do the same.

```sql
SELECT country, count(DISTINCT fruit) AS type, count(*) AS total
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY country;
```

`count(DISTINCT ...)` is comparatively expensive. Depending on Postgres version and data distribution, this may be faster (doing the same):

```sql
SELECT country, count(*) AS type, sum(fruit_ct) AS total
FROM  (
   SELECT country, fruit, count(*) AS fruit_ct
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Comment: @BlueSulley: Which of the queries is faster for you?